# Maven package structure changed after build Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, m2e

I created a Maven project in Eclipse. Initially my package structure was like

```
-src/main/java
---com.package1
---com.package2
-src/main/resources
```

When I build the project successfully and got war deployed in tomcat, My project structure changed to

```
-src.main.java.com.package1
-src.main.java.com.package2
-src.main.resources
```

This is generating errors in Java class files in packages import declarations.
I want to restore my original project structure. I have m2eclipse plugin installed in Eclipse.

I also tried Maven>Update Project.. (I read somewhere on Stack Overflow that it will restore the original structure) but it is generating the following error

```
Failed while installing JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 1.1.
org.osgi.service.prefs.BackingStoreException: Resource /Workspace/ProjectName/.settings'      does not exist.
```

Please help how I can restore my project structure back.

Comment: I'm getting this error, and I can see in the file structure that /.settings does exist, but refreshing and building the project isn't helping.

Answer (score 4):

The following helped in my context:

- Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) with Maven embedded
- Multi module project where folder structure is

  - parent P

    - module A
    - module B
- P is a normal Eclipse project while A and B are Maven projects
- P is a closed, A and B are opened
- the error happened in B with message `Resource /P/B/.settings not available`

After opening P again the error disappears and `Project>Maven>Update Project...` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have created the src/main/java and src/main/resources as *normal* folder. Just change them to   *source* folder. It will work.

Steps
1.Go to src folder & Right Click
2.New->Others->Source Fokder
3.Then make the folder structure as /main/java & /main/resources 
4.Then add the packages.